# I cannot start nginx on Plesk server which is running Apache

Tags: nginx, apache2, vps, plesk

I migrated my WordPress websites from shared hosting to a single VPS. I am hosting the websites with a Plesk server. The Plesk is configured to serve the request with an Apache web server and Nginx as a reverse proxy server.

Now, I want to host a static website with Nginx at `/var/www/bloggrammer.com`. I have added the nginx config for the static website at  `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and enabled it at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. I removed the default config file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and change the port number in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/bloggrammer` from 80 to 8080 because apache is already using the default port, 80.

Below is my config file:

```
server {
    listen *:8080;
    listen [::]:8080;

    server_name bloggrammer.com;
    root /var/www/bloggrammer.com;

    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

When I restart nigix using `systemctl restart nginx` I get the following error:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with an error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I ran `nginx -t` for a syntax error in the configuration and I got this:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "brotli" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/brotli.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I ran `systemctl status nginx.service` and get the following:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-01-20 08:12:27 UTC; 16min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 1793904 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

How can I host the static website with Nginx while still having my WordPress websites running on Apache with Plesk?

PS: I am new to Linux machines and VPS hosting. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the hassle of some special configuration that will never work out right there is a very simple way to achieve your goal within Plesk:

Create a subscription for the nginx-only domain. In the "Apache & Nginx settings" disable "proxy mode" for that domain. On the PHP settings, change the PHP handler to "PHP-FPM via nginx". That's it, you will be all set. Your other domain can still use proxy mode (the nginx/Apache combo).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess your suggestion will require me to add the domain to Plesk which is not feasible at the moment because I have exhausted the number of websites I can add to Plesk for the free version that is why I went the other route of hosting the domain directly with nginx in the `/var/www/bloggrammer.com` directory.